# Scrape/Retrieving data from website in <TD> tag with VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I know there are various questions relating to this topic, I have read them and because I am a novice developer I am unable to apply it to my specific situation, i.e after reading everything I still can't get it to work. So I will ask the question for my specific situation. Thanks for the help.

I am trying to work out the vba code to retrieve the data in the following html markup.

```
<td class='overview-last15'><strong>LAST 15:</strong>X6X0X17X1X011X3</td>
```

I want to extract the `X6X0X17X1X011X3` part.

"Last 15" appears 10 times in the full html markup shown below, I want to extract the 15 characters for each one, start with extracting the first one.

I will include the link to the html page because the code is too long to post here. Please 'view source'.

[https://www.ladbrokes.com.au/cache/formguides/formguide-2017-10-28-moonee valley-2.html](https://www.ladbrokes.com.au/cache/formguides/formguide-2017-10-28-moonee%20valley-2.html)

(hope the link works, I tried posting the code and it's too long!)

Thanks in advance

Here is the code I've tried so far

```
Sub testweb()

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Top = 0
objIE.Left = 0
objIE.Visible = True

On Error Resume Next
objIE.navigate ("https://www.ladbrokes.com.au/cache/formguides/formguide-2017-10-28-moonee%20valley-2.html")

Do
DoEvents
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
objIE.Quit
Set objIE = Nothing
GoTo mystart:
End If
Loop Until objIE.readystate = 4 ' 4 is complete

' I've tried all these lines
Dim myData, oHtml
'Set myDadta=oHtml.getElementById("myDiv").getElementsByClassName("overview-table")(0).getElementsByClassName("overview-last15")(0).innerText
'getElementsByTagName("Table")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(1)
'Set myData = oHtml.getElementById("runner 1").getElementsByClassName("overview-table")(0).getElementsByClassName("title-entrant-name")(0).innerText
'Set myDada = oHtml.getElementByTitle("titlerunner-1").getElementsByClassName("overview-table")(0).getElementsByClassName("title-entrant-name")(0).innerText

MsgBox myData

' we quit the application Internet Explorer or close it
'objIE.Quit

End Sub
```

What I want to see is X6X0X17X1X011X3 instead I get msgbox with nothing.

Comment: The VBA code can't be that long!

Comment: Not the VBA code the html

Comment: If you want a VBA solution then we need to see the code with an explanation of where it breaks.

Comment: Remove or comment the `On Error Resume Next` line and see what happens.

Comment: I removed that line and get a Run time error 424. The problem is I don't know how to write the line                                                                             Set myData = oHtml.getElementById("runner 1").getElementsByClassName("overview-table")(0).getElementsByClassName("title-entrant-name")(0).innerText

Comment: I've never used VBA to access IE but if you "early bind" IE by creating a reference to it, you will be able to see its' model when you press F2 in the IDE.  Maybe put the html into an array and work with that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for help on programming. Please understand this answer to be in response to such a request, even though it may not immediately solve your problem.

Start with `Option Explicit` at the top of your code. Then declare all your variables. Fight your way through the maze of what data type each one should be. Avoid the easy solution as much as the automatic ones. They are all too broad. The more precise you can define a data type the better you will understand it, the better you will be able to handle it. Saves a lot of time!

Now take this line of your code.
`Set myDadta=oHtml.getElementById("myDiv").getElementsByClassName("overview-table")(0).getElementsByClassName`
All the `getElement` functions return HTMLElements or IHTMLElements which have properties leading to the innerText or outerText properties which are strings. These strings you can analyse (read) and find out whether you have the correct one. Your above code example assigns the element of the element of the element to an object, and you can't easily find out whether you have the part of the page which contains the text you want to scrape, nor which other part of the site you happen to have caught hold of or which mistake you may have made.
When you look at the way MSDN teaches this subject you will find that they break up the code like this.

```
Dim myDiv as HTMLElement
Dim myClass As HTMLElement
Dim myData As HTMLElement         ' you might have a type here "MyDadta"

Set myDiv = oHtml.getElementById("myDiv")
Set myClass = MyDiv.getElementsByClassName("overview-table")(0)
Set myData=myClass.getElementsByClassName
```

The point is that you are able to check, step by step, what exactly is contained in the element you have specified. After you are sure that you have the correct innerText you might well throw the elements together again in your final code. Frankly, I doubt that you would do that however. Next time the site has a change you may have to repeat your analysis, and then you would have to take everything apart again. Besides, more methodically built code is likely to be more stable. There is no evidence that your more compact code is actually better or runs even one thousandth of a second faster.

The final innerText which contains the string you are interested in is of data type string. You can simply use the Instr function to look for "strong>" and extract the characters before the next "<".

Comment: Thanks for you answer Variatis. I tried everything you suggested. I included Option Explicit at the top and it won't compile now.  I added that segment of code above and now I get an error "Compile Error:User defined type not defined" at Dim myDiv As HTMLElement   What am I missing?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not the best one to advise you on this. When you look at the Intellisense dropdown while writing the Dim statement you will see that there is indeed no `HTMLElement`.  There are lots of HTML...Elements. If you want to invest the time and learn which one you are looking for you will have the advantage of Intellisense helping you with the methods and properties. Else, Dim myDiv As Object and try to guess the properties. myDiv should have an Items collection, meaning you can ask for myDiv.Items.Count. Then, each Item([Index]) should have an innerText property.

Comment: So, `Debug.Print myDiv.Items(0).innerText` should give you something. I am just trying to get back into a scraping project a did a few months back (my first) where I got so disgusted with all this that I dispensed with all the getElement functions. I just took `HtDoc = IE.Document.body.outerHTML` (where HtDoc is a string) and did all the parsing without Microsoft's functions. Therefore I also didn't need any of the associated objects.